# How to set displacement when using MPI_Gatherv to handle vector of structs?

Tags: mpi

For the following code (this is not the whole program; it is only a code snippet), I do not know how should I set the displacement array to use MPI_Gatherv. Because the result of getBrdy is variable for each rank; I have to use `MPI_Gatherv`. As I searched, I am not sure whether the same way that people use for types like `int` or `string` is still true when I am sending messages as vectors of structs.

```
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); 
int rank,size;
    int  totalLengthBuffer,localSize; 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
int *receiveCount = new int[size];
    int *disps = new int[size];
std::vector<struct Bdry> temp;
temp=this->getBdry(rank); 
    localSize=temp.size(); 
 MPI_Allreduce(&localSize,&totalLengthBuffer,1,MPI_INT, MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
 std::vector<struct Bdry> buffer(totalLengthBuffer); 
constexpr std::size_t num_members=3; 
int lengths[num_members]={1,1,3};
MPI_Aint offsets[num_members]={
    offsetof(struct Bdry,ID),offsetof(struct Bdry,Part), offsetof(struct Bdry,coord)
};
MPI_Datatype types[num_members]={MPI_INT,MPI_INT,MPI_DOUBLE};
MPI_Datatype type;
MPI_Type_create_struct(num_members,lengths,offsets,types,&type);
MPI_Type_commit(&type);

for(emInt i=0; i<nPart;i++){
     receiveCount[i]= this->getBdry(i).size();
     

}
 MPI_Gatherv(temp.data(), temp.size(), type,
            &buffer, receiveCount, const int *displs,
            type, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
MPI_Type_free(&type); 
MPI_Finalize();
```

My structure is in this form:

```
 struct Bdry{
    emInt ID;
    emInt Part; 
    double coord[3];
 };
```

Comment: note your program assumes rank 0 already knows how much data each task will send (to populate `receiveCount`), if this is correct, you can skip the `MPI_Allreduce()` to get `totalLengthBuffer`. try `displs[0] = 0` and `displs[i] = displs[i-1] + receiveCount[i-1]`

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet I corrected displs and it works fine for the case that temp.size() from processors is not variable, but when each rank sends different temp.size(), it gives the error of  MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE. Any idea?

Comment: `receiveCount[i]` must be equal to `temp.size()` on rank `i`, otherwise the call is not invalid and you can end up with such an error.